# In regards to the Hindley-Milner Algorithm, what does a type constructor mean?

Tags: functional-programming, type-inference, hindley-milner

Say I have the letters `A, B` representing type variables which are initially unbound and `a,b,c` representing type constructors. I need then to show the bindings of type variables obtained through unification (or explain why if it fails).

I'm given the following pair of types:

```
a(A,b(c)) and a(B,A)
```

I have two questions:

1) What do they mean by *type constructor?* to me this; `a(A,b(c))`, looks like `a` is the type constructor here which is a function taking two parameters.

2) Can someone show me what approach they would take? I looked here to understand the concept: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/Lectures/lec26-type-inference/type-inference.htm